# grammatical usage of "had" and "that" in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> Occasionally **had** members **that** have been roundly censured in the national press.

I tried to make this sentence simple to understand. Like this,

"Had members that have been censured."

If I could remove 'had' and 'that', it would be "members have been censured." I can understand this sentence. But I'm pretty sure I cannot omit them. They look essential components in this sentence.

If so, I cannot even find what is a verb of this sentence.

"Had members that have been censured."

What is the "had" and "that"???

The whole article link is here (the sentence is the first sentence in 5th paragraph) : http://www.ielts-mentor.com/reading-sample/academic-reading/28-ielts-academic-reading-sample-3-zoo-conservation-programmes

Comment: The initial sentence just doesn't make any sense. Transforming it won't help.

Comment: @curiousdannii But this is a IELTS reading part practice tests. So.... maybe miss typo??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of misformatting in the text.

Comment: @Cascabel Will I be penalized?

Comment: Of course not! The question will just close and no other answers will be allowed. Do not worry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a matter of misformatting. The correct sentence is

> The greatly respected American Association of Zoological Parks and Aquariums (AAZPA) has had extremely dubious members, **and in the UK the Federation of Zoological Gardens of Great Britain and Ireland has occasionally had members that have been roundly censured in the national press.**

The verb of both parts of the sentence is *has had*.

The original puts a line space in the middle of the sentence:

> The greatly respected American Association of Zoological Parks and Aquariums (AAZPA) has had extremely dubious members, and in the UK the Federation of Zoological Gardens of Great Britain and Ireland has
>
> Occasionally had members that have been roundly censured in the national press.